# Why create a PR doesn't trigger the Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, github

I have a repo and I want to setup Jenkins with Github. I'm new in this and read a lot of articles about it, and yet I have a question.

When I create a PR to push branch into the master, I want to run the build in Jenkins. if it failed, then I can't be able to marge this PR into the master.

I see when I create a PR, github say: "Checking for ability to merge automatically..."

[image]

And then it change to:

[image]

Github say that "Continuous integration has not been set up".

Which is weird, because I already setup a build in Jenkins.  And I checked the "Pull Reuqest".

[image]

What else I need to do to let Jenkins know about create the PR, if the build failed then tell to github that PR is not able to merge. and if success then its okay to move to merge phase.

Something must be missing, and I don't know what.

Comment: Also select pushes. this is required when you commit on a PR. Is the build starting in Jenkins when you create a PR?

Comment: even I checked the "pushes" the Jenkins dones't trigger the build when PR is create. only when the PR is merge. but when I checked the "pushes" then every push is trigger the build, and I want only when PR is created and when PR is merged then trigger the build.

Comment: Could you give more info about your jenkins setup. what is your multibranch pipeline setup. (the github discovery part)

Comment: its just simple pipeline with build, tests stages, from Jenkinsfile